# Problemas con fecha javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 90,
    select = document.getElementById('selectYear');

for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectYear">
</select>
```

Lo utilizo para que me popule en un select los años, desde el año actual a 90 años menores a este.

Lo que quisiera pudieran ayudarme es como lograr el mismo resultado, pero en vez de que me presente los años desde (1927 hasta 2017) me los presente (2017 hasta 1927)

Alguna Sugerencia

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Modificar el for. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo es cuestión de modificar el `for` para iniciar en el valor `Max` hasta llegar al Valor `Mínimo` , además ir `Decrementando` `i` en lugar de `Incrementar`

```js
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 90,
    select = document.getElementById('selectYear');

for (var i = max; i>=min; i--){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="selectYear">
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta con modificar el ***for***, haciendo algo asi:

```js
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 90,
    select = document.getElementById('selectYear');

for (var i = max; i >= min; i--){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectYear">
</select>
```

Lo que le indicamos es que en lugar de ejecutarse de manera Ascendente, se ejecute de manera descendente.

```
for (var i = max; i >= min; i--)
```

Recorre el bucle del elemento mayor al elemento menor.

Comment: jjajaja FAST AND FURIOS 9 Stack over Run xD

Comment: @Victor-Random :)

Comment: @IvanBotero tener cuidado con la condición del for , llega a `1927`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Corregido

Comment: jajaj Gracias me hubiera gustado dar elegir las dos ya que son certeras pero Gracias